# After Yeoman scaffolding, "grunt serve" not working

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I followed the [Yeoman tutorial](http://yeoman.io/codelab/preview-inbrowser.html) to the T yet it doesn't work for me.

I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Imray\Projects\myProj\v2>grunt serve
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'rimraf'
Loading "watch.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'

Running "serve" task
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-12-14 15:38:18 UTC)
loading tasks  9ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 45%
serve          9ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 45%
Total 20ms
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have the dependencies properly installed.

Do a `npm install` and `bower install`, after successfull completion try `grunt serve` again.